# How to get the SQL string from $this->db->insert('history', $data) is building and sending to the db codeigniter?

Tags: sql, codeigniter

On an insert or get function of the db i am getting empty result. 
I wanted to get the sql string build by the codeigniter to put it directly to mysql and check the query if some thing goes wrong or not.

Questions are:

- How can i get the SQL string build by CI Query Builder?
- How can i get the error messages if any error happens in query?

I have tried these without success

- $this->db->error();
- $this->db->_error_message();
- $this->db->_error_number();

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$dec_data = json_decode($data);
$request = $this->Book_model->insert_transcation($data_req);

$data_hist = $this->get_data_transaction($request);

$this->db->insert('trans_history', $data_hist);

 function get_data_transaction($filter)
    {
            $this->db->select('*,'
                . '(promo_credit) as promo_credit');
            $this->db->from('transaction');
            $this->db->where($filter);
            $res = $this->db->get();
            return $res;

        }
```

User request is put into a table called transaction, then cross check if any promotion available for the transaction. and this data is put into the user history table.

But I am getting empty value for get_data_transaction. I wanted to check against the DB with the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

after every query executed by CI like insert or get. you will have SQL string of last executed query.